# Question on algebraic equations: $\frac{2ax}{ab+a+1}+\frac{2bx}{bc+b+1}+\frac{2cx}{ca+c+1}=1$ for $abc=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If positive numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ satisfy $abc=1$, solve the equation in $x$
> $$\frac{2ax}{ab+a+1}+\frac{2bx}{bc+b+1}+\frac{2cx}{ca+c+1}=1$$

I tried thinking about it to somehow get the expression in the form of $abc$ but O couldn't find an appropriate way till now.

Comment: ohh right wow thanks got it, i cant believe i didnt think of that...

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The last denominator should be $ b + 1 + bc$.

Comment: Here is the same problem on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h555835p3230404 Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B2ax%7D%7Bab%2Ba%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2bx%7D%7Bbc%2Bb%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B2cx%7D%7Bca%2Bc%2B1%7D%3D1%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the LHS is linear in $x$. So, if you didn't mind having variables in the expression,

$$ x = \frac{ 1 } { \frac{ 2a}{ab+a+1} + \frac{ 2b} { bc+b+1} + \frac{2c}{ca+c+1}}.$$

Of course, this isn't quite pleasing / satisfactory.

---

**Hint:** $ ab+ a + 1 = ab + a + abc = a ( bc + b + 1)$.
Likewise, $ ca + c + 1 = ca + abc^2 + abc = ac (bc + b + 1) $

Make common denominator, and hence solve for $x$.

> $ 1 = \frac{ 2acx + 2abcx + 2 cx } { ac (bc+b+1)} = 2x$

Comment: thanks a lot, i couldnt think abt the c term before, this is an interesting example for the ways in which u can manipulate equations